# json array string conversion to nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, json, nsmutablearray

I am getting Json response from server.

```
       type = 2;
      "daysofWeek" = "(\n    Mon,\n    Tue\n)";
       serviceType = 2;
       startDate = "2013-10-28";
```

In above format daysofWeek is Array string. I am trying to convert into NSMutableArray as

```
  NSString *weekDaysStr=[valueDict objectForKey:@"recrWeek_daysofWeek"];
  NSMutableArray *weekDays=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[weekDaysStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
```

But when i log this array i shownig as

```
     ("\n    Mon",
      "\n    Tue\n"
     )
```

How to remove those extra words from array.

I have check each values to week day.

```
               NSString *day=@"Mon";
               if([day isEqualToString:[weekDays objectAtIndex:0]){

                }
```

I tried this type also

```
       weekDaysStr=[weekDaysStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(\n" withString:@""];                      
       weekDaysStr=[weekDaysStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n)" withString:@""];
    weekDaysStr=[weekDaysStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n " withString:@""];
     weekDaysStr=[weekDaysStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];                                   
     weekDaysStr=[weekDaysStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""]; 
     weekDaysStr=[weekDaysStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

it showing as

```
        "Mon",
        Tue
```

At that time its giving false condtion.Help me on this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to trim the strings in the array yourself:

```
for (NSString *myString in weekDays)
{
    myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString:@""];
    myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\n" withString:@""];
    myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"(" withString:@""];
    myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @")" withString:@""];
}
```

Comment: Yes i tried .    weekDaysStr=[weekDaysStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(\n" withString:@""];
    weekDaysStr=[weekDaysStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n)" withString:@""];
    weekDaysStr=[weekDaysStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n " withString:@""];
    weekDaysStr=[weekDaysStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"   " withString:@""];
    weekDaysStr=[weekDaysStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
    weekDaysStr=[weekDaysStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@""];       But i showing comments for first element

Comment: like   "Mon",Tue  this

Comment: i Tried.in nslog  week days::(
    "(Mon",
    "Tue)"
)   displaying

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will help

```
NSString *str=@"(\n    Mon,\n    Tue\n)";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]; 
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n)" withString:@""];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
NSMutableArray *weekDays=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
NSLog(@"%@",weekDays );
```